# Advanced Codeigniter Search by multiple keywords

Tags: search, codeigniter-3

I want to search with codeigniter a certain number of keywords in database in multltiple rows.

My code looks like this:

```
$search = array('search goes here');
$keywords = explode(' ', $search);

        $this->db->like('nume', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('id', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('description', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('code', $search);
        $query = $this->db->get('property');
        $config['total_rows'] = $query->num_rows();
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $this->db->like('nume', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('id', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('description', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('code', $search);
        $this->db->limit($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));
        $this->db->order_by('added_date', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get("property");
        $properties = $data['properties'] = $query->result();
```

What i want is something like:

```
foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
//some code that will search the database by each keyword
}
```

Comment: If you want to get query result by all words in search parameter, best way would be to use [Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). Especially pay attention on [Natural Language Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) and [Full-Text Searches with Query Expansion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html).

Comment: I want to search like on google in my application. For example: if i search "2 rooms apartment in miami". I want to see all apartments that have 2 rooms in miami not only the ones that has in theyr description that full text

Comment: Full text search is ok solution if you allow visitor to type custom query. It is faster too if there is big amount of rows in table. I am not sure what would be better model for you explicitly without more details, but you can after last `$this->db->or_like()` line put your foreach loop with repeating `$this->db->or_like('nume', $keyword);$this->db->or_like('id', $keyword);//etc`. Check if you need to use `$this->db->distinct();` to get rid of doubled results.

Comment: It would be far better to pin down a query in pure SQL before attempting to run it through active record